# Find Missing Numbers

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a big list of ordered files with name like this (videos)

```
S1-E18-(Date)-(Title)-(Random numbers).mp4
```

Here is the example of list

```
S1-E1-20100526-title-of-video-1400316375.mp4
S1-E3-20100547-title-of-video-15457547.mp4
S10-E5-20100463-title-of-video-14467457.mp4
```

In this case its easy to see that the files `S1-E2` and `S10-E4` are missing.
but if I have a big list then how can I find the missing files.
(Leave Season number `S1, S2`) just need to check `E` means episode number

The largest existing file's number is `S50-E2184`  and
The Smallest existing file's number is `S1-E1`

Comment: Hi! This is a question for stack overflow. People here only really answer questions about Ubuntu directly.

Comment: @LewisSmith not really, text processing is very much on topic here in practice. Just look at the numerous posts on AU on the topic.

Comment: Are the lines/numbers sorted in the file?

Comment: @JacobVlijm - My apologies. In that case ignore me.

Comment: @LewisSmith no need to apologize! Everything is subject to discussion. What may be practice today may be different in a year or so :).

Comment: @JacobVlijm files are not sorted in the file. and there are one line per number

Comment: @muru strictly taken, I agree with you. It is however not fair not to allow this one, while I am sure OP would find any other lamguage acceptable. Just like many questions ask for a grep, awk or bash solution, but have an accepted answer in another language.

Comment: Agreed, @EliShain please clarify if you are looking for a strictly python based solution, or if another language would be acceptable to you.

Comment: @muru the consequence is than that we ask anyone asking for grep, awk, bash etc. the same question. Never seen a close vote on those.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, Any other language is acceptable.

Comment: @muru and others please retract your close vote, see comment by op above.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F- '{n = substr($2, 2)} (n - prev) != 1 {for (i = prev + 1; i < n; i++) print i} {prev = n}' input-file
2
4
```

- `-F -` sets the field separator to `-` (so `S1`, `E1`, etc. become different fields).
- Then we extract the episode number (`n = substr($2, 2)`), by taking everything but the first character from the second field (`$2`).
- If the episode number is not the previous episode + 1 ( `(n - prev) != 1`), we print all the numbers in between.
- We save the current episode number in `prev` for the next iteration.

If the output isn't sorted, split up the extraction and check to insert a `sort` in between:

```
awk -F- '{print substr($2, 2)}' input-file | sort -n | awk '{n=$1} (n - prev) != 1 {for (i = prev + 1; i < n; i++) print i} {prev = n}'
```

Comment: Mind that the lines aren't sorted (yet)

Answer (score 1):

A bit more straight forward script.
The script assumes the last episode exists and extracts its episode number. Then it iterates over [1..last] and check the existence of all episodes in between. Note this would not work for episodes numbered with leading zeroes.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "please specify season prefix"
fi

# extract last episode number
last=`ls $1-*.* -1 --reverse | head -n 1 | grep --only-matching "E[[:digit:]+]" | cut -c 2-`

for ((i=1; i<=$last; i++)); do
    if [ ! -f $1-E$i-*.* ]; then
        echo "missing episode $i"
    fi
done
```

The script takes the season prefix as its first argument, i.e. S1